# Close button opens new chrome store tab on Chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension, popup

We have a Chrome extension download button on our site.

When you click it, it opens a popup that says 'Add extension', 'Cancel' etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCeib.png [image: Popup I'm referring to]

The image shows the popup I'm referring to.

It works fine, except for the cancel button opens a new tab and takes you to the plugins chrome store page.

I have no idea why it does this, or how to just get it to cancel.

The js:

```
chrome.webstore.install(webStoreURL, () => null, (error, errorCode) => {
   window.open(PLUGIN_LINKS.Chrome, '_blank');
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Whats the value of PLUGIN_LINKS.Chrome ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you indiscriminately try to open the Webstore page on "error". In fact, user clicking Cancel is one of [many "error" conditions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webstore#type-ErrorCode).

You need to analyze the `errorCode` to filter that out.

```
chrome.webstore.install(webStoreURL, () => null, (error, errorCode) => {
   if (errorCode !== "userCanceled") {
       window.open(PLUGIN_LINKS.Chrome, '_blank');
   }
});
```

Note: as is obvious from the error code list, there are many other conditions that make opening the Web Store page useless. You should re-think this logic.